# pandas groupby; if condition: sum else: max for given column based on another column

Tags: python, pandas

Say for `df` I do a groupby on `group`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,4), columns=list('abcd'))
df['group'] = [0, 0, 1, 1]
```

then I want to collapse the df so that A is summed if the sum of B is greater than 1 and I want the max of A if the sum of B is less than or equal to 1.

Then I want the min() of B and other various operations on the remaining columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better performance use [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
np.random.seed(15)
N = 1000
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(N,10), columns=list('abcdefghij'))
df['group'] = np.random.randint(100, size=N)

df_grouped = df.groupby('group')
s1 = df_grouped.apply(lambda grp: grp['a'].sum() if grp['b'].sum() > 1 else grp['a'].max())
print (s1)

df_grouped = df.groupby('group')
s2 = df_grouped['a'].sum().where(df_grouped['b'].sum() > 1, df_grouped['a'].max())
print (s2)


In [69]: %%timeit
    ...: df_grouped = df.groupby('group')
    ...: s1 = df_grouped.apply(lambda grp: grp['a'].sum() if grp['b'].sum() > 1 else grp['a'].max())
    ...: 
24.8 ms ± 228 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [70]: %%timeit
    ...: df_grouped = df.groupby('group')
    ...: s2 = df_grouped['a'].sum().where(df_grouped['b'].sum() > 1, df_grouped['a'].max())
    ...: 
1.63 ms ± 58 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with `apply`:

```
df_grouped = df.groupby('group')
df_grouped.apply(lambda grp: grp['a'].sum() if grp['b'].sum() > 1 else grp['a'].max())

group
0    0.834666
1    1.096652
dtype: float64
```